# Update commerce cart block when product added through ajax

Tags: views, ajax

Hii How can I update **commerce_cart_block** when my product is added through **ajax**.
Any suggestion will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your custom ajax call (or how is your setup ?) with an update cart ajax command, there's a module for it named: [commerce_ajax_cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_ajax_cart)

If you want it all out of the box, then use the [dc_ajax_add_cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/dc_ajax_add_cart) module.

Comment: I am using this module

Comment: Can you explain how should I use this module I have enabled this but not getting how to use this module

Comment: ok - if you don't have custom code, then you should use a different module dc_ajax_add_cart. I edited the answer.

Comment: I have already tried dc_ajax_add_cart infact this provide a view block

Comment: Yes with this module you need to replace the default commerce cart block.

Comment: Yes its working

Comment: Cant I do it by using commerce_ajax_cart module

Comment: Please explain how you add the product via AJAX

Comment: I am using Commerce Cart Ajax

Comment: I have a view which I show on header on click of cart icon I just want to update that view when ajax fires

Comment: this is a custom view ? when what fires you want to update this view ?

Comment: How can i update my custom view

Comment: Actually this is a new question! . You would need to overwrite dc_ajax_add_carts behavoir http://cgit.drupalcode.org/dc_ajax_add_cart/tree/js/dc_ajax_add_cart.js?id=7bd8f71 and invoke the triggerHandler as here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138347/view-ajax-refresh-causing-multiple-refreshes